# RabbitMQ java client is not able to connect with TLS

Tags: rabbitmq

**Goal:**  I am researching on RabbitMQ's passwordless authentication. My aim is for a simple java client to connect to RabbitMQ server with TLS

**Platform**:

- rabbit-server version 3.7.7
- erlang version 21.0.1

**Steps taken according to the documentation:**

I am  referring to the documentation at https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html

1) I have generated CA, Certificates, private keys as mentioned in (https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html#manual-certificate-generation)

2) The essential settings related to TLS  is done in rabbitmq.config as follows (https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html#enabling-tls):

```
[{
    rabbit, [
    {
        tcp_listeners, [5672]
    },{
    tcp_listeners, [{"127.0.0.1", 5672},
                     {"::1",       5672}]
    },
    {password_hashing_module, rabbit_password_hashing_sha512},

    {auth_mechanisms, ['PLAIN', 'AMQPLAIN', 'EXTERNAL']},

    {ssl_listeners, [5671]},

    {ssl_options, [{cacertfile, "/path/to/ca_certificate_bundle.pem"},
                    {certfile,   "/path/to/server_certificate.pem"},
                    {keyfile,    "/path/to/server/private_key.pem"},
                    {password, "password"},
                    {verify,     verify_peer},
                    {fail_if_no_peer_cert, false}]}
    ]
}].
```

3) I have verified that TLS is enabled in the log file (https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html#enabling-tls-verify-configuration)

4) I am setting up a simple example java client to RabbitMQ server over TLS without validating certificates as mentioned in https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html#java-client-connecting

**Issue:**

After I run the code, I get a **socket timeout exception** as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.sendHeader(SocketFrameHandler.java:147)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.sendHeader(SocketFrameHandler.java:153)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:285)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:62)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:99)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:900)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:859)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:817)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:954)
        at Example1.main(Example1.java:17)
```

In Example1.java the line fails at Connection conn =  factory.newConnection();

I have searched on the net for this exception, but the solutions offered do not seem to be related. Can you please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: When you refer to java-client-connecting in step 4, you mean you took the code example as is, or you inspired yourself from it? Could you confirm the port you're targeting in your example is 5671?

Comment: I took the code from their example. With port 5671 I am getting socket timeout exception

Comment: Please follow the troubleshooting guide and advice we provided in the [`rabbitmq-users` thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/rabbitmq-users/ou5TKnF1ivg/discussion) and report back there. Thanks.